# MaterialUI Pickers keyboard doesn't maintain its original date when editing

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using `Material UI Pickers`, but when i try to edit a single character, it enters edit mode and the previous value is cleared and i have to type the date from the beginning
[Here is a test case show this issue:](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-swirles-1erpy?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)
The test case was made from [Material UI demo page](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datepicker)
My expected behavior is so that i can change a single character when editing, i should mention that this behaviors does work in the Demo site of `Material UI` but creating a test case fails to reproduce the same results

Answer (score 1):

I've used [date-fns](https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/blob/v2.8.1/src/locale/fa-IR/snapshot.md) library and imported the farsi locale:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import format from "date-fns/format";
import faLocale from "date-fns/locale/fa-IR";

import {
  KeyboardDatePicker,
  MuiPickersUtilsProvider
} from "@material-ui/pickers";

class LocalizedUtils extends DateFnsUtils {
  getDatePickerHeaderText(date) {
    return format(date, "P", { locale: this.locale });
  }
}

const InlineDateTimePickerDemo = props => {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date());

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={LocalizedUtils} locale={faLocale}>
      <KeyboardDatePicker
        clearable
        format="mm/dd/yyyy"
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={date => handleDateChange(date)}
        minDate={new Date()}
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
};

export default InlineDateTimePickerDemo;
```

Comment: +1 because your answer managed to produce a working example, but it uses a different `utils` which will change the shape of the calendar (in this case its not localized for farsi and uses Gregorian calendar), and also when i try using the example you provided in my project, when i set the date to say for example `12/13/2019` i get `46/13/2019`, which is a weird outcome and i don't where it comes from, in any case thanks for your answer, but is it possible for you to tell me what is wrong with the original testcase? and how this utils plays a part in it?, maybe i can fix my current date picker?